# What about the Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Like every year we are so excited to wearing Hats!!!! This is really a great event & amazing concept. Waiting to here about this event.

I believe new users will enjoy much like the old.

Hopefully this year would be even more awesome. Good luck everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will be hats again. The site is already online: https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/ but it doesn't have much content yet. Feel free to bookmark it and [refresh... refresh...](https://xkcd.com/281/)

Comment: There isn't any content since Winter Bash didn't start, yet. I take the question is for gathering consensus about enabling it for _Drupal Answers_, since the single sites opt in to it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Winterbash has been opt-out in recent years...

Comment: Well, then the question is for opting-out from Winter Bash, which is what we would do if the question gets many down-votes. :)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016/11/28, [winter bash has not been officially announced yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287412/when-will-winter-bash-2016-begin).  When it is, one of the mods will make a MDA post to gather whether we want to opt-out for 2016.